# select2 dropdown not choosing new value when in mobile view , select2 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

It's working fine in the regular view with this code:

```
.profile-searchbar.text-left                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  = form_tag(compare_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: 'compare_form') do                                                                                                                                                        
    = select_tag "v_friend_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@v_friends, 
    :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id), 
    :include_blank => true, :class => "compare-search"
```

however, in mobile view which renders on mobile (bootstrap col-xs) It will not update the selected value. It stays on the original one. If I change it in the regular view, then scale the screen down, it shows a new value, but I cannot select one with this select2 form in mobile view. It seems to only select the default value.

Here's the select2 option in my mobile view I made a separate dropdown, because the design does not allow for simply scaling down the original select2 dropdown:

```
= form_tag(compare_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: 'compare_form') do                                                                                                                                 
  = select_tag "v_friend_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@v_friends, 
  :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id), 
  :class => "compare-searchM", :style => "width:90%; margin-left: 3px;"
```

here's my JS for select 2:

```
 $('.compare_btn').on('click', function () {
      $("#compare_form").submit();
    });

 $(".compare-search").select2({
      placeholder: "Search to compare",
      allowClear: true
    });

    $(".compare-searchM").select2({
      placeholder: "Search to compare",
      allowClear: true
    });
```

Basically, it seems I'm needing 2 selct2 dropdowns / forms to control the same value.. But, I think only the original is controlling it..